# Redux reducer state returns an empty Object in component

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I am fairly new to React Native and Redux. I am fetching data on Restaurants from an API route using axios,and my goal is to display the Restaurants, but when I console.log in the components I get an empty object {}.

Here is my data sample:

```
[{
"id_supplier":1,
"supplier_name":"Grill Park",
"supplier_description":"Order food at Grill-Park. Masters of Italian Pizza.",
"supplier_image":"restaurant1.jpg",
"createdAt":"2020-08-28T21:00:00.000Z",
"updatedAt":"0000-00-00"
},
{
"id_supplier":2,
"supplier_name":"Bobbies burger",
"supplier_description":"Order a burger on the go. Beef, Cheese, Hamburger, Vegan Burgers",
"supplier_image":"restaurant2.jpg",
"createdAt":"2020-08-28T21:00:00.000Z",
"updatedAt":"0000-00-00"
},
{
"id_supplier":3,
"supplier_name":"Chicken n licken",
"supplier_description":"Renowned for serving tasty fried chicken pieces and a wide range of other menu items.",
"supplier_image":"restaurant3.jpg",
"createdAt":"2020-08-28T21:00:00.000Z",
"updatedAt":"0000-00-00"
},
{
"id_supplier":4,
"supplier_name":"French House Tarvern",
"supplier_description":"Grab a sandwich at our Pick 'n' Mix Sandwich hip and fun environment",
"supplier_image":"restaurant4.jpg",
"createdAt":"2020-08-28T21:00:00.000Z",
"updatedAt":"0000-00-00"
}]
```

Here is my model:

```
export interface RestaurantModel {
  id_supplier: number;
  supplier_name: string;
  supplier_description: string;
  supplier_image: string;
  createdAt: Date;
  updatedAt: Date;
}

export interface RestaurantState{
    restaurants_avail: RestaurantModel;
    //add others
}
```

My action file looks as follows

```
export const getRestaurants = ()=>{
    return async(dispatch : Dispatch<RestaurantAction>) =>{
        try{
            const response = await axios.get<RestaurantModel>(`${BASE_URL}/restaurants`)
                 console.log("respond now", response.data)//This returns an array of the restaurants
                if(response){
                    dispatch({
                        type: 'ON_GET_RESTAURANTS',
                        payload: response.data
                    })
                } else {
                    dispatch({
                    type: 'ON_RESTAURANT_ERROR',
                    payload: 'RESTAURANTS UNAVAILABLE'
                })
                }
           }catch(error){
            dispatch({
                type: 'ON_RESTAURANT_ERROR',
                payload: error
            })
        }
    }
}
```

When I console log the value of of the **response.data** an array of the restaurants is returned.

My reducer code looks as follows

```
const initialState: RestaurantState = {
    restaurants_avail: {} as RestaurantModel,
}

const RestaurantReducer = (state: RestaurantState = initialState, action: RestaurantAction) =>{
    
    switch(action.type){
        case 'ON_GET_RESTAURANTS':
            console.log(action.payload)//this returns the updated state as expected
        return{
            ...state,
            restaurants_avail: action.payload
        }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

I have all my reducers combined in **rootreducer** then my store looks as follows.

```
const store = createStore(rootReducer,composeWithDevTools(
     applyMiddleware(thunk))
     )
   console.log("Value of store state", store.getState())
export {store};
```

store.getState() returns empty objects.

Here is how I intend to print out the array in my Component.

```
interface HomeProps {
  restaurantReducer: RestaurantState;
  getRestaurants: Function;
}

    const _HomeScreen: React.FC<HomeProps> = (props) => {
  
      const { restaurants_avail } = props.restaurantReducer;
      console.log("restaurants array",restaurants_avail)//This returns an empty object

  useEffect(() => {
console.log(props.getRestaurants())//This return an array object with all the restaurants
})
```

I don't understand where am going wrong as console.log(restaurants_avail) should print out the array, but it instead returns an empty {}

Here is the React Native Debugger state chart.
[image]

Comment: Try the useSelector hook to get something from state

Comment: Also, as you are learning redux right now, please follow the official tutorials: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/index
The style of redux you are using here is not recommended to learn for over a year now and will end up with you writing 3-4 times the code you would write with modern redux. Whatever tutorial you are following right now is probably very outdated.